# Workbox PWA - service worker on iOS not handling image files referenced in CDN-hosted CSS

Tags: progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, workbox

We've a PWA, with a workbox-based service worker, installing in standalone mode.

Our main css file is hosted on a CDN (Cloudfront) - with the correct CORS (as are our images and other static files).

Everything works as expected on Android/Chrome. Image files referenced in the css file get handled by the service worker and served from the cache.

On iOS/Safari, any image files that are required within the CSS file go straight to network - the cache for these files is never used. The service worker doesn't seem to handle these requests at all.  If I host the css file locally rather than on CDN the iOS issue goes away.

Is this a known iOS issue - or is there a possible fix?